# Magento 2: How to display text in one line product catalog

Tags: magento2

I added the text before the price in list.phtml, here is my code:

```
<span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Retail price:') ?></span><?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

[image]

Only I can not display it in one line in any way. Can anyone help?

I want to display in one line:
Retail price: 125,00 zł 100,00 zł

@ update result

[image]

is correct in one line but still now no display price

@ update 2
[image]

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage it by css. Add this css in your **style.css** :

```
.product-item .price-box
{
    display:inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 18% 0 0;
}
```

It will working. But, It may be not good idea.

Comment: Ok, so leave it as it is! I think it's OK too! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome :) Happy Coding ..!!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo sprintf(__('Retail price: %s'),  $block->getProductPrice($_product)) ?></span>
```

**Other solution:**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

```
    <span class="old-price">
TEST
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
                'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
                'include_container' => true,
                'skip_adjustments'  => true
            ]); ?>
        </span>
```

Comment: Abhiskeh I have update my topic.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Now price is displayed but still "retail price" is above :(

Comment: can you send me link?